# Reading Excel Sheet - Strings As Factors and Skipping Rows

Tags: r, excel

I've used the `readxl` package extensively to import data from Excel sheets into R. However for a particular application I need to import the data such that some of the fields are represented as factors in R, and as far as I can tell, the `readxl` functions (`read_excel`, `read_xlsx`) can't do this. I also need to skip the first few rows of each Excel sheet, but that's easy using the `skip` option.

I thought this might be an alternative:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RcmdrMisc/versions/1.0-6/topics/readXL

since it does have a `stringsAsFactors` option. But it doesn't seem to let me skip the first n rows of each sheet. So perhaps it's not going to be helpful here.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this please?

I could of course convert all the relevant fields to factors in my R code, but this will be long winded - something I had hoped to avoid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to change the columns you want to be factors as an additional call to reading in the excel sheet. I haven't used readxl extensively but I imagine something like this where you find the columns that are of type character and change them to factors.

```r
my_sheet <- read_xl("path/to/sheet.xls") %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor))
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I want to convert characters to factors. In other words, I'd be setting stringsAsFactors to be TRUE if I could!

Comment: The second line should work perfect for that then. If there are some columns that you'd like to keep as characters you can adjust the across() call to specify the specific columns you want to turn into factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which columns should be converted to factor by using:

```
df <- read_excel("name.xlsx", sheet =7)

str(df) # Verify the respective numbers of the variables to be converted 

df <- **strings2factors**(df, which =  c(4,5,6))
```

Comment: what is strings2factors?